# A function that returns the number of even numbers of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I need to write function that returns the number of even numbers of an array.

```
//======================  EXAMPLE  ========================
isEven([2,4,8,7])
3 // <======  EXPECTED OUTPUT
isEven([1,9,66,"banana"])
1 // <======  EXPECTED OUTPUT
//=========================================================
```

I wrote this:

```
function isEven(arr) {
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
                count++;
                document.write(count);
            }
        }
    }
```

But to me it just returns undefined I don't know why.

Comment: That's because you don't return anything else... WTH

Comment: It returns undefined because you never return anything so by default js functions return undefined in that case

Comment: You're document.writing, not returning

Comment: You should also really avoid `document.write`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One actually does never want to mix computation logic with whatever kind of output code.

In addition one could make use of [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and a precise filter condition which does target `odd` and/or `even` **number values** ... something similar to the next provided example code ...

```js
function getEvenCount(list) {
  return list.filter(item =>
    (typeof item === 'number') && (item % 2 === 0)
  ).length;
}
function getOddCount(list) {
  return list.filter(item =>
    (typeof item === 'number') && (item % 2 !== 0)
  ).length;
}

document.write(
  'getEvenCount([2,4,8,7]) ... ' +
  getEvenCount([2,4,8,7]) +
  '</br>'
)
document.write(
  'getEvenCount([1,9,66,"banana"]) ... ' +
  getEvenCount([1,9,66,"banana"]) +
  '</br>'
)
document.write(
  'getOddCount([2,4,8,7]) ... ' +
  getOddCount([2,4,8,7]) +
  '</br>'
)
document.write(
  'getOddCount([1,9,66,"banana"]) ... ' +
  getOddCount([1,9,66,"banana"]) +
  '</br>'
)

console.log(
  'getEvenCount([2,4,8,7]) ... ',
  getEvenCount([2,4,8,7])
);
console.log(
  'getEvenCount([1,9,66,"banana"]) ...',
  getEvenCount([1,9,66,"banana"])
);
console.log(
  'getOddCount([2,4,8,7]) ...',
  getOddCount([2,4,8,7])
);
console.log(
  'getOddCount([1,9,66,"banana"]) ...',
  getOddCount([1,9,66,"banana"])
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `document.write`, and return the count outside the loop which fixes the undefined issue.

```
function isEven(arr) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

There are [alternatives to document.write](http://www.java2s.com/example/javascript/dom/alternatives-to-documentwrite.html), which allows browsers to implement optimisations that have to be disabled when using `document.write`.

Use [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log) for debugging to the browser console.

Comment: I will do that! I'll keep learning alternatives for document.write. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Because the function doesn't [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) anything.  Instead, it just writes to the HTML document (repeatedly, on every iteration of the loop).

Return `count` at the end of the function:

```
function isEven(arr) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 === 0) {
            count++;
            document.write(count);
        }
    }
    return count; // <--- here
}
```

As an aside, you should get out of the habit of using `document.write` at all.  If you want to view information for debugging purposes, use `console.log` to log it to the browser's development console.  If you want to see output on the page, look into how you identify and update the text/HTML of DOM elements on the page instead.

The [example section here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) might be a good place to start.  Basically you use something like `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector` to identify a specific HTML element on the page, then set its `innerHTML` or `innerText` property to the data you want to display.  (It can get much more involved than that as you continue to learn and build more features.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll keep on studying those selectors.