# A function that takes an array as an argument and extracts all the strings of the array and puts them into a new array:

Tags: javascript, function, loops

Ihave to write a function that takes an array as an argument and extracts all the strings of the array and puts them into a new array:

```
//======================  EXAMPLE  ========================
isString([3,55,66,"hello"])
["hello"] // <======  EXPECTED OUTPUT
isString([3,55,66,"hello","beer",12,{},[],()=>{},"[]"])
["hello","beer","[]"]  // <======  EXPECTED OUTPUT
//=========================================================
```

I wrote this:

```
function isString(arr){
    if(typeof arr[i] === 'string'){
     arr2.push(arr[i]);
 }
}
```

But I get undefined I don't know why.

Comment: You should get `ReferenceError: arr2 is not defined`. There is no definition or initialization for `arr2`.

Comment: Litterly almost the same problem as the question you asked a few hours ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68806850/a-function-that-returns-the-number-of-even-numbers-of-an-array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A function that returns the number of even numbers of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68806850/a-function-that-returns-the-number-of-even-numbers-of-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function isString(arr){
        var arr2 = [];
        arr.forEach(el => {
            if(typeof el === 'string'){
             arr2.push(el);
            }
          });
          return arr2;
        }
    console.log(isString([3,55,66,"hello","beer",12,{},[],()=>{},"[]"]))
```